# How to measure image download time on client side for my website?

Tags: web, image, latency

In the Img tag, we know that the image has an OnLoad event that fires when the images finish loading. But can we get the accurate measure when the image begin to download? I am trying to measure a website's Page Load Time, so knowing how long it takes for an image to load will be part of my analysis if that's possible.

I would like to do it from an automated fashion, so I can measure real client experiences instead of putting my website on Yslow or PingDom( http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/). I have tried to look into Navigation Timing Apis (http://w3c-test.org/webperf/specs/NavigationTiming/) unfortunately even they provide insights such as DNS resolution time, but resource fetching within the web request doesn't seemed to be supported.

Comment: Later on I found that the W3C's performance group is developing an API specifically for solving this problem named Resource Timing API http://www.w3c-test.org/webperf/specs/ResourceTiming/. Unfortunately at this point major browsers are still building this API. See Google IO's Demo by this link: http://io12-webperf.appspot.com/#12

Answer (score 2):

You can start to experiment with whether the Resource Timing API will meet your needs useing either IE10 of the Chrome Dev Channel - getEntriesByName is the method that's probably most use for a single resource.

I wrote a primer form the Performance Advent Calendar http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/an-introduction-to-the-resource-timing-api/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that IE10 & Windows Phone 8 has already had it implemented! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/network) on Firefox or the [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) in Chrome to get information on page resources.

Comment: But can I do it in an automated fasion? Because I would like to get real world client's experience instead from developer's point of view. Using Firebug and Developer's will help in development phase but once the website is out in production as a developer, I would like to get the real page load time.

Comment: I've not used it, but BrowserHawk claims to be able to do this http://www.cyscape.com/products/bhawk/page-load-time-details.aspx