# Is it possible the break down the XHR network performance using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, xmlhttprequest

I have one XHR request.
I would like to understand how much it took from sending the request to getting the response.
and I want to be able to say it spent X time in the server and Y time on the network

Comment: Do you need that information in JavaScript, or only for debugging?

Comment: In runtime (JavaScript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure image download time on client side for my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994572/how-to-measure-image-download-time-on-client-side-for-my-website) (being similar to XHR)

Comment: You can try http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/, but it's not widely supported. That way, you can only record the timestamps of the `readyStateChange` events.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?  Please upvote or accept an answer if so.

Comment: no...I guess that the answer is that it's impossible to do via javascript...

Answer (score 1):

you can use date object to get the time, before sending request you can store time stamp in a variable and when it returns (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200) you can get another time date object to get time and then take the difference.

Using IE -- > Press F12 --> then network --> capture network --> every thread you can see.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the **developer tools** in Chrome or Firebug in FF to view
   network traces of your requests.
2. You can also look at **server side** logs of your application.  I use
   log4j, so it is easy to see time stamps.
3. If you want to use **only javascript** code to accomplish this, I would
   say to use `console.log`.  You can create a wrapper around it to
   always print the date.  Be careful if console.log is not defined.

Here is a little js wrapper:

```
log : function(message, debugType) {
    var str = new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + ", "
            + ((debugType) ? debugType : "INFO") + ", " + message;
    console.log(str);
}
```

Then you can call it before and after your XHR.

Comment: Chrome's network tab does a really good job of describing the sequence of XHR's.

Comment: I want to achieve the goal via only client-side code ( JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Log the time that you initiated the request and store it in a variable
2. Log the time as soon as the server receives it and store it in a variable
3. Log the time when the server has finished the processing and include the time at the start and the end of the processing in the response to the client
4. Log the time that the client receives the response.

From these four timestamps you should be able to determine how long it took the server to receive the request, how long it took to process the request, how long it took the client to receive the response and the total time.

It won't be 100% accurate but it will be close.

Comment: I want to achieve the goal via only client-side code ( JavaScript) - so I can't log anything on the server side